# Making a function that displays a variable's name and its value

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable

I want to write function (let's call it superEcho) that takes a variable name as input. The function should print that variable's name and its value

```
function superEcho
{
     echo "$1: ?????"
}

var=100

superEcho var
```

I want this script to return

```
var: 100
```

But I don't know what should I put instead of "?????" in the superEcho function.

Answer (score 8):

POSIXly:

```
superEcho() {
  eval 'printf "%s\n" "$1: ${'"$1"'}"'
}
```

Like for the `bash`-specific `${!var}`, that expects `$1` has been sanitized and contains a valid variable name. Otherwise, that amounts to an arbitrary command injection vulnerability.

You could do the sanitization in the function:

```
superEcho() {
  case $1 in
    ("" | *[!_0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]* | [0123456789]*)
      printf >&2 'Invalid variable name: "%s"\n' "$1"
      return 1;;
    (*) eval 'printf "%s\n" "$1: ${'"$1"'}"'
  esac
}
```

Note that for variables of type *array* or *associative array*, in `bash` or `ksh` (POSIX `sh` has no array except `"$@"` which you couldn't use here as that would be the arguments of the `superEcho` function itself) that only prints the value of the element of indice `0`, while in `zsh`, that would output the concatenation of the *values* with the first character of `$IFS` (and with SPC characters in `yash`).

In `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash` or `yash` (the 4 Bourne-like shells with array support). See also `typeset -p var` to print the definition and attributes of a variable.

Comment: Any particular reason why you have to list out the 26 times 2 alphabets? When the range 0-9 is understood then why not a-z ?

Comment: @Rakesh, `[a-z]` is locale-dependant and generally includes a lot more than those 26 characters (and the POSIX spec and most (though not all) shells won't have those in variable names). Alternative would be to start a subshell and have `export LC_ALL=C` in it.

Comment: @Rakesh, POSIX doesn't guaranteed that `0-9` only matches `0123456789` either (except in the `C`/`POSIX` locale of course), but in practice it does. I'd consider broken a locale where that's not the case.

Comment: @Rakesh I've now realised that many locales on many systems were "broken" in that regard and changed it to 0123456789

Answer (score 2):

Use `${!variablename}`:

```
function superEcho
{
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$1" "${!1}"
}
```

Comment: Please disregard my previous (now deleted) comment if you happened to see it. I was being silly.

Answer (score 1):

I do it another way around. I often want to use the variable name for e-mails, logs or flags (written to the disk) so that everything belonging to one device is named the same way - using the variable name as the base.

```
RPiZero=10

ReadRPiTemp ()
{
    eval ReadSegment='$'$1
    echo "variable content: $ReadSegment"
    echo "variable name: $1"
}

ReadRPiTemp RPiZero
# NOT ReadRPiTemp "$RPiZero"
```

Above will work in sh and bash. As I need to be compatible with sh in my work, I neglected to mention a proper way to do the same in Bash.

```
RPiZero=10

ReadRPiTemp ()
{
    declare -n ReadSegment=$1
    echo "variable content: $ReadSegment"
    echo "variable name: $1"
}

ReadRPiTemp RPiZero
# NOT ReadRPiTemp "$RPiZero"
```

Both of the above will print out the same:

```
variable content: 10
variable name: RPiZero
```